# Selecting and changing SELECT OPTION amount in php

Tags: php, html, paypal

So i have the following code for example

```
<select class="form-control" name="amount" >
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="100">100</option>
      <option value="200">200</option>
</select>
```

When i select the option like 100 $ or 200 $ i want the page to process php directly after selecting the option and change the selected value without using any extra submit or update button.
I can't add the submit or update button because after the option is selected the desired value needs to added in the paypal amount value, which is another part.
I just need it to submit the form directly when the option is clicked.

Comment: Auto submit form is a bad practice, it should be avoided

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like

```
<select class="form-control" name="amount" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could think about an easy straight-forward way using the `.trigger('submit')` when selecting an option. So you trigger the submit-event on change (on selecting an option) and then you aork with it. The actual value (e.g 100) will be accessed by `.val()`. This value is then send via ajax to you php script.

```
$('.form-control').on('change',function(){
   $(this).trigger('submit');
});
```

And in your submit-Handler you check the value:

```
$('.form-control').on('submit',function(){
    var data = $('.form-control').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'your.php',
      type: 'POST', //GET
      data: data,
      success: yourSuccessHandling();
    })
});
```

I recommend you to use an `id` for your selection to exactly speak with it.